# Is it possible to create a PERSISTED column that's made up of an array of specific JSON values and if so how?

Tags: singlestore

Is it possible to create a PERSISTED column that's made up of an array of specific JSON values and if so how?

Simple Example (json column named `data`):

```
{ name: "Jerry", age: 91, mother: "Janet", father: "Eustace" }
```

Persisted Column Hopeful (assuming json column is called 'data'):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD parents [ data::$mother, data::$father ] AS PERSISTED JSON;
```

Expected Output

```
| data (json)                                                    | parents (persisted json) |
| -------------------------------------------------------------- | ------------------------- |
| { name: "Jerry", age: 91, mother: "Janet", father: "Eustace" } | [ "Janet", "Eustace" ]    |
| { name: "Eustace", age: 106, mother: "Jane" }                  | [ "Jane" ]                |
| { name: "Jim", age: 54, mother: "Rachael", father: "Dom" }     | [ "Rachael", "Dom ]       |
| -------------------------------------------------------------- | ------------------------- |
```

The above doesn't work, but hopefully it conveys what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `PERSISTED ARRAY` data type for columns, but there is a [JSON](https://docs.memsql.com/v7.0/reference/sql-reference/datatypes/#json-type) column type that can store arrays.

For example:

```
-- The existing table
create table tablename (
  id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT
);

-- Add the new JSON column
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD column parents JSON;

-- Insert data into the table
INSERT INTO tablename (parents) VALUES
    ('[ "Janet", "Eustace" ]'),
    ('[ "Jane" ]');

-- Select table based on matches in the JSON column
select *
from tablename
where JSON_ARRAY_CONTAINS_STRING(parents, 'Jane');

-- Change data in the JSON column
update tablename
set parents = JSON_ARRAY_PUSH_STRING(parents, 'Jon')
where JSON_ARRAY_CONTAINS_STRING(parents, 'Jane')

-- Show changed data
select *
from tablename
where JSON_ARRAY_CONTAINS_STRING(parents, 'Jane');
```

Check out more examples of pushing and selecting JSON data in the docs at https://docs.memsql.com/v7.0/concepts/json-guide/

Comment: My source data is being stored in JSON, I want to extract an array made up of data from separate locations in the JSON data I'm already storing so that's it's computed as part of the storage instead of at the time of the query

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample table definition where I do something similar with customer and event:

```
CREATE TABLE `eventsext2` (
  `data` JSON COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `memsql_insert_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `customer` as data::$custID PERSISTED text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `event` as data::$event PERSISTED text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
customerevent as concat(data::$custID,", ",data::$event) persisted text,
  `generator` as data::$genID PERSISTED text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `latitude` as (substr(data::$longlat from (instr(data::$longlat,'|')+1))) PERSISTED decimal(21,18),
  `longitude` as (substr(data::$longlat from 1 for (instr(data::$longlat,'|')-1))) PERSISTED decimal(21,18),
  `location` as concat('POINT(',latitude,' ',longitude,')') PERSISTED geographypoint,
  KEY `memsql_insert_time` (`memsql_insert_time`)
  /*!90618 , SHARD KEY () */ 
) /*!90623 AUTOSTATS_CARDINALITY_MODE=OFF, AUTOSTATS_HISTOGRAM_MODE=OFF */ /*!90623 SQL_MODE='STRICT_ALL_TABLES' */;
```

Comment: It is not a persisted array but persisted text and could have JSON syntax added and stored as persisted JSON

Answer (score -1):

Though not your question, denormalizing this table into two tables might be a good choice:

```
create table parents (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  tablenameid int not null,
  name varchar(20),
  type int not null, -- 1=Father, 2=Mother, ideally foreign key to other table
);
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm trying to accomplish.